# Resolving JSP Session Logout

Tags: jsp, jsp-tags

I have encountered an error as such in logout.jsp

```
 org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 
  An error occurred at line: 2 in the jsp file: /logout.jsp
 session cannot be resolved
  1: <%@ page language="java"  session="false" %>
  2: <%session.invalidate();%>
  3: <%
  4: final String queryString = request.getQueryString();
  5: final String url = "http://www."testxxxxx".com/login.php?login_process=1&cas=1";
```

Why it shows that session cannot be resolved

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps because line 1 says session=false

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/tags/11/syntaxref11.fm7.html)

> session="true | false"

The default value is true.

This is to specify whether the client must join an HTTP session in order to use the JSP page. If the value is true, the session object refers to the current or new session. If the value is false, you cannot use the session object or a  element with scope=session in the JSP file.